# Populate drop down menu Grails

Tags: grails, drop-down-menu, grails-controller

I am currently trying to populate a drop down menu based upon the selection in the previous drop down menu I have. For example if you click on Spring 2013 in the first drop down menu the second menu will show all the respective weeks assigned to that semester so that one can be chosen and modified. How do I propagate the second menu with respects to the choosing from the first menu?

This is my controller:

```
    class TermController {

    static scaffold = Term

    def dataSource

    def list = {
        def db = new Sql(dataSource)
        def result = db.rows("SELECT id, semester FROM term")
        [ result: result ]
    }

}
```

Here is my list.gsp to show the view of the controller:

```
    <div class="fieldcontain">
        <g:select name="termSelection" from="${Term.list()}" values="${params.id}" optionKey="id" optionValue="semester" noSelection="['':'----Term----']"/>
    </div>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <g:select name="it.week" from="${Week.list()}"/>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: How does the domain classes look like? And what is the use of `list` action in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to make an ajax call triggered by the selection change of another list?

- Listen to changes in your *termSelection* list
- Upon changes, make an ajax call to retrieve the list of weeks
- Feed the retrieved ajax List to your *it.week* list